# How do I use JSON from a Jekyll _data directory?

Tags: javascript, json, jekyll

According to the Jekyll docs [you can access YAML, JSON, and CSV files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) in the `_data` directory using `{{ site.data.filename }}`.

I have a valid geoJson file of point features called `chapters.json`.  I'm able to access the file, but I'm seeing some strange characters when I use the file in my javascript.

`chapters.json` excerpt:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "MaptimeBER"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.391,
          52.521
        ]
      }
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```

For example, when Jekyll processes the following:  `var chapters = {{ site.data.chapters }};`

The output Javascript is:

`var chapters = {"type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>[{"type"=>"Feature", "properties"=> ...`

**My question is, why does the colon separating key-value pairs change to `=>`?  It's causing my javascript to error out.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the **jsonify** filter, it convert Hash or Array to JSON :

```
var chapters = {{ site.data.chapters | jsonify }};
```

Comment: Is this just how jekyll/ruby represents objects?

Comment: Yes, **site.data.chapters** is a [Ruby Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html)